# Cloud9 AWS CLI - how to determine CIDR for security group?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, cloud9-ide, cidr, aws-cloud9

I'm using Cloud9 IDE and AWS CLI to manage EC2 instances.  I'm going through the AWS guidance on configuring security groups and trying to determine what CIDR I should use when creating a new security group (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/tutorial-ec2-ubuntu.html)

Here is the sample command from the guidance:

$ aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name devenv-sg --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr 0.0.0.0/0

Thanks.

Comment: What is the IP(s) of the machine(s) that you want to access your instances?

Comment: Isn't the cidr the ip/port that I'm trying to figure out?

Comment: No. Based on the IP(s) you want to let access your instance(s), you can come up with one or more CIDRs.

Comment: Is this the correct command to run to determine the appropriate IP address:  dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com

Comment: Cloud9 IDE hosted workspaces have dynamic IP addresses. Here is a list of IP addresses that these may fall under: https://community.c9.io/t/workspace-ip-addresses-to-whitelist-on-firewall/150. If you'd prefer a static IP address then you'll need to use an SSH workspace with a Digital Ocean droplet or an AWS EC2 instance.